# Safe to remove bower, dotnet-bundle

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

In my ASP.NET Core app, I want to use WebPack for a number of front-end tasks e.g. transpiling via Babel, bundling, minification, etc.

Is it safe for me to remove the following:

- .bowerrc file
- bower.json file
- bundleconfig.json file

and the following line from project.json

```
"prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ]
```

I think I'll also have to remove the following lines from myProject.xproj:

```
<DnxInvisibleContent Include="bower.json" />
<DnxInvisibleContent Include=".bowerrc" />
```

Is there anything else I need to remove? I want a clean project with no unnecessary files or references. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is safe.

No need to remove the stuff from `.xproj` though, its only there to hide these files from the Solution Explorer.